# Using the S3 client from the AWS SDK for Go without credentials

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I am using the Go AWS SDK to access an object in an S3 bucket. I instantiate `s3.S3`, then call

```
s3client.GetObject(...)
```

The object I am accessing is publicly accessible, so I do not wish to provide any credentials. However, if I do not provide any credentials then I get the following error:

```
NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.\n\tFor verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

Comment: The item is publicly accessible through a public url. But you cannot access a bucket without credentials.

Comment: @Himanshu can I use the AWS SDK for Go to get the public URL for an object? I know I could construct it manually but I'd rather not.

Comment: When you are uploading an to AWS S3 bucket using GO SDK, They actually provide you a location of where the object is stored in the response. This is public location which is actually a url to the aws bucket along with the region added and bucket name.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the session:

```
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Credentials: credentials.AnonymousCredentials,
        ....
    }))
```